# Access Date Filters on Linked Tables Fails - Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, firebird, ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 application where I have linked tables to an outside database, in this case it is Firebird SQL database.

The table in question is actually a Firebird SQL view.  In this view I have a column that is stored as a database DATE type.  From this access linked table, I created a datasheet view.

The problem I am facing is when a user attempts to filter this date column by the Today, Tomorrow and Yesterday date filters that are offered in the column header.

Attempting to filter nets this error message:

```
 Data type mismatch in criteria expression
```

Debugging the ODBC connection to expose the SQL statements used on the connection does not show any SQL level filtering, so I assume it is happening in application.  Other questions seem to indicate an issue with the escaping of the dates, but I'm not generating a SQL Query at all.  Just trying to use the Date Filters offered in Access out of the box.

Everything other than Today, Yesterday, Tomorrow work just fine.

Comment: What do you mean with 'Today, Yesterday, Tomorrow'? Those are not actual dates; is it a standard filter provided by Access or something you added yourself?

Comment: This is not the exact platform image, but its representative of the Access UI: http://officeimg.vo.msecnd.net/en-us/files/735/242/ZA010100087.gif